# Render data on home (index) page odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want render data on home (index) page, below is my example:

controller:

```
import openerp.http as http
from openerp.http import request

class TestController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/index',auth='public',website=True)
    def list(self,**kw):
        Test9 = http.request.env['test.9']
        arr = Test9.search([])
        print arr
        return http.request.website.render('website.layout',
               {'test9':Test9.search([])
     })
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="test9" name="Test9" page="True">
            <t t-call="website.layout">
                <div class="oe_structure">
                  <div class="container">
                    <center><h3>Details</h3></center>
                    <t t-foreach="test9" t-as="company">
                      <h4><span t-esc="company.name"/></h4>
                      <table class="table-striped table">
                        <tr>
                          <td>Name:</td>
                          <td><span t-esc="company.name"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>City:</td>
                          <td><span t-esc="company.city"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Place:</td>
                          <td>
                            <td><span t-esc="company.place"/></td>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </t>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

After run http://localhost:8069/index in console get two record

Where is problem in my code?

................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

```
import openerp.http as http
from openerp.http import request

class List(openerp.addons.web.controllers.main.Home):

    @http.route('/', type='http', auth='none', website=True)
    def index(self):
       Test9 = request.env['test.9']
       arr = Test9.search([])
       print arr
       return request.render('YOUR_MODULE.test9',
           {'test9':Test9.search([])
       })
```

Comment: On  http://localhost:8069/index return data on http://localhost:8069/ is empty!  How get data on home page, which is default name in odoo for that?

Comment: i Update my answer

Comment: use method name as 'index'.

Comment: Ohh. you need to override the controller of base web module to achieve this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150277/discussion-between-viki-chavada-and-user-odoo).